# S-W correlation plot from positron annihilation Doppler broadening spectroscopy

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, nuclear-physics, material-science, spectroscopy

From Doppler broadening spectroscopy, we get the S-parameter and W-parameter. I found a S-W correlation plot in many research papers. What information does this plot provide?

Comment: I do not understand the connection between Doppler and positron annihilation. The gamma line at 511 keV is narrow, it is difficult to measure its width.

Comment: You need detectors having a high energy resolution power. We are using high purity germanium detectors for this purpose.